# How can i convert JSON to Java object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, gson

Hi I am having a JSON of following format

```
{
"elements":[
        list1,
        list2,
        list3
    ]
}
```

where list1,list2,list3 are all javascript arrays.

Now I am able to pass this to my controller(am using spring mvc) from a javascript file. Now I want to use the data in the JSON that am sending. I want to map this to a model class and return it another jsp page.
I didn't create a model yet. how can i pull this off?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at jackson library

Comment: I've posted an answer, but if you provide info about the content of `list1`, `list2` and `list3`, we could give a more precise solution...

Answer (score 2):

use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert your JSON into java

```
YourModelClass obj= gson.fromJson(json, YourModelClass .class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [**Gson**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), you first need to create a class structure representing your JSON data, so you can create a class like this:

```
public class Response {
    private List<List<YourObject>> elements;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Note that I use class `YourObject` since you don't specify what type your arrays contain... If the arrays contain just strings for example, replace `YourObject` by `String`. If the arrays contain a different object you have to create a class representing the data in your JSON, such as:

```
public class YourObject {
    private String attribute1;
    private int attribute2;
    private boolean attribute3;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Then, in order to actually parse your JSON response, you just have to do:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, Response.class);
```

And your JSON data will be used to fill your class structure, so you can access the fields, for example:

```
String attribute1 = response.getElements().get(i).get(i).getAttribute1();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MikO. I need more practice on json conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I used the following code and its working great.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonParser.parse(this.plan).getAsJsonArray();
    ArrayList<PlanJson> planJsonList = new ArrayList<PlanJson>();
    for(JsonElement jsonElement:jsonArray)
    {
        System.out.println(jsonElement);
        PlanJson planJson = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, PlanJson.class);
        planJsonList.add(planJson);
    }
```

I found it to be the most easiest to work out for my json structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jackson library. see: http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Here is an example from: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

```
package com.mkyong.core;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {

        // read from file, convert it to user class
        User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User.class);

        // display to console
        System.out.println(user);

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative @meewoK. However I was not trying to add anymore libraries to my application.

Comment: @user2182000 ok, no problem :)